# Perl substr to create fixed length filename from time and PID

Tags: perl, substr

I'd love some assistance or a 'second pair of eyes' on this small code project.
I am responsible for fixing up some old Perl code, which will be running on a new web server.
The code takes the time in seconds (since 1970), concatenates a dash, concatenates the server process ID number to create a variable length file name. And then uses that file and name in a lot of downstream processes.

Filename create code is:  $output_file = "$time-$$";

The problem I have is that the on the new server, the PID can be up to 6 (or 7?) digits, while the old server never saw more than 5 digit PID. And the rest of the downstream perl scripts all expect a maximum of 5 digits in that PID file name portion (programs quit ungracefully when encounters 6 digits in the PID part of file name).

So what I am trying to accomplish is end up with a Filename which will always be a fixed length of 16 characters. Composed of the 10 digit time code, a dash, and a 5 digit PID number (the rightmost 5 digits if PID is > 5 chars).

I tried creating a Perl testing script to see if I could work on the PID data value.
 (a) Use the substr command to trim back the PID data to 5 if it is 6 or 7 digit chars,
 (b) or increase to 5 chars with leading zeros if less than 5, again using the substr command.
The (a) case of making it shorter seems to work OK,
But the (b) case of trying to make it larger acts inconsistently on the server.

I'd like to avoid grep and regular expressions if at all possible.
Anything which will be hard for me or other support folks to decipher later on will not be useful.

My test script is structured as it is to allow me to ensure that all my test cases will generate proper expected results. (And I may be doing something totally wrong/dumb with it...)

I am pasting in:
(a) my test script, (b) a screen snap of the server results.
The Server PERL Version: 5.10.1

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
# 
# Name: testsubstr2.pl
# 
my $pidnum7 = "1234567";
my $pidnum6 = "123456";
my $pidnum5 = "12345";
my $pidnum4 = "1234";
my $pidnum3 = "123";
my $pidnum2 = "12";
my $pidnum1 = "1";

if ( length( $pidnum7 ) == 7 )
{ print "This is 7 char PIDnum7. Length = ", length( $pidnum7 ), ", Content: ", $pidnum7, "\n";
 my $subst7  = substr ($pidnum7, -5, 5);
 print "  Now shortened as SUBst7 to: ", length($subst7), ", Content: ", $subst7, "\n";
 print "  Orig PIDnum7 is length: ", length($pidnum7), ", Content: ", $pidnum7, "\n";
}
else { } # do nothing
# this 7 down to 5 seems to work ok.

#elsif ( length( $pidnum6 ) == 6 )
if ( length( $pidnum6 ) == 6 )
# else the string is 6 (or less)
{ print "This is 6 char PIDnum6. Length = ", length( $pidnum6 ), ", Content: ", $pidnum6, "\n";
 my $subst6  = substr ($pidnum6, -5, 5);
 print "  Now  shortened as SUBst6 to: ", length($subst6), ", Content: ", $subst6, "\n";
 print "  Orig PIDnum6 is length: ", length($pidnum6), ", Content: ", $pidnum6, "\n";
}
else { } # do nothing
# this 6 down to 5 seems to work ok.

#elsif ( length( $pidnum5 ) == 5 )
if ( length( $pidnum5 ) == 5 )
# else the string is exactly 5, do nothing
{ print "This PIDnum5 is exactly 5 char PIDnum, Length = ", length( $pidnum5 ), ", Content: ", $pidnum5, "\n";
}
else { } # do nothing. Fine as is.

#elsif ( length( $pidnum4 ) == 4 )
if ( length( $pidnum4 ) == 4 )
# else the string is 4, too short
{ print "This is 4 char PIDnum4. Length = ", length( $pidnum4 ), ", Content: ", $pidnum4, "\n";
 my $subst4  = substr ($pidnum4, 0, 0, "0");   #insert character '0' in front
 print "  After substr command, PIDnum4 = ", length($pidnum4), ", Content: ", $pidnum4, "\n";
 print "  Now PID4 in variable SUBst4 is length: ", length($subst4), ", Content: ", $subst4, "\n";
# Weird Result in this code block, the var $pidnum4 becomes 5 chars, 01234, though it should not have changed
# but the temp var $subst4 becomes 0 charcters with Blank (no) content. It should I thought become the 5 character receiver.
# something wrong with this block of code.
}
else { } # do nothing
```

Here is a Snaggy link to my test script run [server test results](https://snag.gy/UaTGIZ.jpg)

(The bottom 7 lines on result screen are from some generic substr command examples which I included in my test script, probably not needed so I left them out of my code example above.)

Thank you.

Comment: This smells like an `XY problem` - what are you trying to accomplish? Timestamp is a file-metadata, so you don't need to include it in the filename. And `pid` is _usually_ a uniqueness thing. So ... why not use `Data::UUID` or `File::Temp` instead?

Comment: My constraint is that this web site and Perl scripts system was developed in the late 90's, to create a guaranteed unique filename. Thus the time-in-seconds plus a PID-number. The name has no particular significance itself. Since there are many script functions and HTML coded pages that expect this filename form, and cannot handle the filename if the PID portion is longer than 5 digits, I am stuck with making it work.      I do not have the authorization from mgnt team (of the parent nonprofit) to recode the entire site. So -- gotta make it work as best I can.

Comment: Plus already existing on the current production website are thousands of data files using this name form.   Was a valid question to raise though, wish the original coders had been a bit more expansive in their thinking on this.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `sprintf` and modulo, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my $pid = $_;
        my $time = time;
        my $fn = sprintf("%s-%05d", $time, $pid % 100000);
        print "$fn\n";
}
__DATA__
1
12
123
12345
123456
7654321
```

Output:

```
1485862025-00001
1485862025-00012
1485862025-00123
1485862025-12345
1485862025-23456
1485862025-54321
```

Does this meet your needs?

Comment: This is probably how I'd tackle it, given the constraints. Although, I think I'd probably look at _not_ using "time-pid" filenames, and instead use `Data::UUID` or `File::Temp` depending on specific use case.

Comment: That looks interesting and I will give it a look-see.  Though, My test script might have misled you all, as I have it go through 7 tries because I wanted to make sure that the substr (or whatever command) was working for all cases of different PID length encountered.  In real-life the live full script will only be creating one file name at a time.  Thus will only run once per filename data creation.  So I will check it from that perspective. Thx.

Comment: I think I've finally wrapped my head around the modulo operation (took a bit). So by subtracting (so to speak) as many 100,000 chunks as possible from the PID value, we will end up with the remainder which will always be less than 100,000. that is, it will be a max value of 99,999 which is 5 digits. And thus gives us the rightmost 5 digits of any length PID. wow, interesting. I never would have thought to go at it that way. I was attempting string character position manipulation.   I will create some test scripts and check them on my parallel dev system.   Get back to you later. thx. :)